# How do I elegantly upload my working paper on SSRN?

Tags: soft-question, academic-graduate, research

I am an academic novice. Recently, I have a working paper that I want to upload to SSRN. I have several questions that I wish to get answers to:

1. Will registering SSRN with a private email address impact credibility or other dimensions? I am a Ph.D. candidate and have an institutional mailbox. But considering that I am about to graduate, the institutional mailbox may expire in the future, so I used a private mailbox to register.
2. Does SSRN send confirmation emails to co-authors of our working papers?
3. SSRN was acquired by Elsevier a few years ago. Will this affect the submission of working papers uploaded to SSRN to journals not owned by Elsevier?
4. Uploading to SSRN will disclose your research to the public. If you submit to a journal next, the journal's editors cannot theoretically conduct a double-blind review (because the reviewer can find the authors of the paper). Will this affect the submission?
5. How to submit papers already uploaded to SSRN to journals?
6. Once the paper is accepted and published by a journal, will the citations obtained during the openness on SSRN be transferred to the officially-published version? Or will the citation count re-accumulate from zero?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 4):

> Will registering SSRN with a private email address impact credibility or other dimensions? I am a Ph.D. candidate and have an institutional mailbox. But considering that I am about to graduate, the institutional mailbox may expire in the future, so I used a private mailbox to register.

For registration you can feel free to use your personal email, people can't see your login email on SSRN.

After you register SSRN will allow you to select affiliations (which are visible to other users). You can enter there multiple affiliations (see picture below). These affiliations can be always updated so do not worry about your institutional email expiring. Once it expires you can replace it with your new institution or you can even put independent if you decide not work for academic institution after you graduate

[image]

> Does SSRN send confirmation emails to co-authors of our working papers?

When you are adding coauthors you can either do it via search on SSRN (for coauthors) or manually. If you use the search function they will get notified since the paper will show on their SSRN papers list. If you do it manually I don't know what happens but I do not think they contact the coauthor.

> SSRN was acquired by Elsevier a few years ago. Will this affect the submission of working papers uploaded to SSRN to journals not owned by Elsevier?

You should always inquire about this at your target journal but majority of journals do not count SSRN or other preprints as prior publication (however, perhaps there are exceptions there are hundreds of journals, nobody can know editorial policies of all).

> Uploading to SSRN will disclose your research to the public. If you submit to a journal next, the journal's editors cannot theoretically conduct a double-blind review (because the reviewer can find the authors of the paper). Will this affect the submission?

Yep, this is sad truth. In the age of google double blind review is nearly impossible since you will rarely publish an article that you did not even presented at any conference (e.g. it is really rare to produce good paper without zero feedback from wider academic audience). As a consequence once you present that paper at any non-trivial open workshop or conference or circulate it among peers in any way people will be always able to google you when peer reviewing. This being said I would not worry about it too much. Many journals do not even have double blind review policies anyway.

> How to submit papers already uploaded to SSRN to journals?

You have to check the submission guidelines of every journal separately. You submit it the same way as if you would never use SSRN in the first place.

> Once the paper is accepted and published by a journal, will the citations obtained during the openness on SSRN be transferred to the officially-published version? Or will the citation count re-accumulate from zero?

It is my understanding that on google scholar citations accumulate from all versions of your paper published. If you are using some different way of counting citations then that might not be the case.